# In spite of the condition $i \ne j$, why is $E[Y_iY_j] = \mu^2$?

Tags: variance, expected-value

I am following the derivation of the expected value of the sample variance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance

In the penultimate step, they do the substitution $E[Y_iY_j] = \mu^2$ where $i \ne j$. I am having trouble understanding this step. As an example, if I use numbers from 1 to 10, then $\frac{1}{N^2} \sum y_i y_j = 30.25$ when i and j are allowed to be the same. However, $\frac{2}{N(N-1)} \sum y_i y_j = 29.33..$ when I impose the condition $i \ne j$.

Comment: Note that when $i=j$, $E(Y_iY_j)=\mu^2+\sigma^2$ (I get the impression you may have thought otherwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe here they use that independence between X,Y  implies $$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y).$$

Hence it’s not in spite of but because $i \neq j$ that the equality holds.

Comment: I think I understand now. I should think of $Y_i$ and $Y_j$ as random variables. So in fact it is allowed for these variables to take the same value e.g. 3 for both $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. In the derivation, we just want to separate out the terms that are guaranteed to be the same ($Y_i^2$).